# struts xml validation not working

Tags: xml, validation, struts2

I tried to add every possible solution and patches and but things are not working . the program bypass the validation every time

I am trying to implement email validation

My Project Structure

[image]

I tried different dtd schema , but it all same . How can i get a clue what is wrong with validation

my index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  
<html>  
<head>  
<STYLE type="text/css">  
.errorMessage{color:red;}  
</STYLE>  
</head>  
<body>  

<s:form action="register" method="post" validate="true">  
<s:textfield name="email" label="Enter Email Id"></s:textfield>  
<s:submit value="register"></s:submit>  
</s:form>  

</body>  
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
<action name="register" class="com.RegisterAction">
<result name="input">index.jsp</result>  
<result>welcome.jsp</result>   
</action>  
</package>

</struts>
```

RegisterAction.java

```
package com;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport{  
    private String email;  


    public String getEmail() {  
        return email;  
    }  


    public void setEmail(String email) {  
        this.email = email;  
    }  


    public String execute(){  
        return "success";  
    }  

    }
```

register-validation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC   
        "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"   
        "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">  

        <validators>  

        <field name="email">  
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">  
        <message>Email Id can't be blank</message>  
        </field-validator>  
        <field-validator type="email">  
        <message>Please enter correct email id</message>  
        </field-validator>  

        </field>  



        </validators>
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  

Email Id is:,<s:property value="email"/>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but please indent your XML properly so it's legible. I'd also recommend using an updated S2 version; that's over a half-decade old.

Comment: your Struts version is too old. Upgrade to the recent one.

Comment: ok , will update the struts version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the validation file name to `RegisterAction-validation.xml`